# Is it possible to do this "half strikethrough" using CSS (without using images)

Tags: html, css, strikethrough

I'm doing a site without using any images, to make it responsive and faster, only CSS(3).
I'm trying to do the following effect using CSS

[image: pseudo strikethrough in Illustrator]

I used to do this using

```html
<div class="strikethrough">
  <span>Ou</span>
</div>
```

and the CSS (using image):

```css
.strikethrough {
  background: url('strip.gif') repeat-x 50% 50%;
}

.strikethrough span {
  background: #EAEBEC;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same using only CSS?

Comment: I'd stick with the image. It's like 200 bytes (if done properly) and is backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="height: 1px; text-align: center; background-color: black;">
  <span style="position: relative; top: -0.5em; background-color: white;">
    Ou
  </span>
</div>
```

or

```
<fieldset style="text-align: center; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid black;">
  <legend>
    Ou
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: is there a way to make it inherit the background of the current page? some pages are white and some pages are light grey, can make it inherit automatically?

Comment: I have added another option to answer.

Comment: Solution 1 is for inline elements and Solution 2 works best with block element.

Answer (score 0):

```
div 
{
text-align: center;
}

span
{
display: inline-block;    
}

span:before,
span:after {
border-top: 3px solid #EAEBEC;
display: block;
height: 1px;
content: " ";
width: 48%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 1.2em;
}

span:after
{
right: 0;  
left: auto; 
}
```

```
<div>
    <span>OU</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm too late, but here it is anyway. -[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/2G8hp/2/)

**Edit**- Added code for `different` style and updated jsFiddle

css

```
.strikethrough{
  box-shadow: 
        0px -10px 0px 0px #EAEBEC inset, inset 0px -11px 0px 0px black;
  background: #EAEBEC;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: block;
    text-align:center; 
}
.strikethrough span{
    background:#EAEBEC;
}

.different{
    background:white;
}
.different .strikethrough{
  box-shadow: 
        0px -10px 0px 0px #fff inset, inset 0px -11px 0px 0px black;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: block;
    text-align:center; 
}
.different .strikethrough span{
    background:#fff;
}
```

html

```
<div class="strikethrough"> <span>&nbsp;Ou&nbsp;</span> </div>

<div class="different">
    <div class="strikethrough"> <span>&nbsp;Ou&nbsp;</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: small advantage to this method. The text will still be inline with normally formatted text

Comment: is there a way to make it inherit the background of the current page? some pages are white and some pages are light grey, can make it inherit automatically?

Comment: It looks like the background color can be inherited, but not box-shadow color. Check out my updated answer for a working method.